# App is force closing (Admob)?

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

I just added adds to my app, but the moment i run it i get a force close from my phone and there is no logcat. I never declared it in my xml but i dont think i need to...

Here's admob.java:

```
package isaac.n;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
import com.google.ads.*;


public class admob extends Activity {
      private AdView adView;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER,  "a14f725ebadc0f2");

        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.main);

        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
      }
    }
```

and here's main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gray3" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="163dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/calc" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:text="@string/Board"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30px"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@null" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:maxHeight="150dp"
        android:maxWidth="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/white1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:src="@drawable/remin1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/notes" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:background="@null" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="170px"
        android:layout_height="170px"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:background="@null" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView2"
        android:background="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="isaac.n"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />


     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application



        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher1"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity android:name="com.admob.android.ads.admob"/>
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>


        <activity
            android:name="isaac.n.IzzynActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="isaac.n.notes"
            android:label="@string/notes"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

           <activity android:name="isaac.n.FingerPaint"
                  android:label="WhiteBoard"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="isaac.n.calculator"
            android:label="@string/calculator"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>


        <activity android:name=".main1"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
    </application>








</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be much better off declaring your adView in your XML code. It will prevent weird stuff such as you are seeing from happening. Here's an example of how to declare it in XML.

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:orientation="vertical" style="@style/background">
  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView" ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" ads:adSize="BANNER" ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_unit_id" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></com.google.ads.AdView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "Unbound prefix" is what eclipse gives me

Answer (score 1):

There should be an error coming out somewhere... also the first thing I see is that your `main.xml` is a `RelativeLayout` but you're casting it at runtime to a `LinearLayout`... change that to see if it helps, then get back to us.

Comment: Ok there is no force close anymore but still there are no ads displaying